# Handle context in a chatbot

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, chatbot

I have made a chatbot, using Tensorflow's [translation model](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq) (with some modifications), by feeding it with message-response pairs from the Ubuntu Dialogue Corpus. **I was wondering if anyone has any ideas about how I can handle context in a conversation?** I.e. I don't want the chatbot to forget what I have previously said, after I enter a new sentence.

I can only think about one strategy, which is to handle the context in the pre-processing. Lets say that I have this conversation:

```
M1: Hi, how are you?
R1: Hey, good! I just finished work at the restaurant. How are you?
M2: Good. How was it?
R2: Exhausting... 
M3: Many customers?
R3: Yes, and they didn't tip well either!
```

Then I could put them in pairs like this: (M1-R1), (R1M2-R2), (R2M3-R3) etc... Another option would be to save the context from M1 in each pair e.g. (M1-R1), (M1R1M2-R2), (M1R1M2R2M3-R3) - but then the length of the training sentences will increase (a lot) - leading to more memory allocating during training and I would probably need to decrease my network (fewer neurons in each layer).

They did something similar in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.06714), but I don't understand how their model is built and how it will handle this.

Comment: did you get any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

[Bot-context](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bot-context) is a cool library which provides an easy way to maintain context. The related [blog post](https://medium.com/@ashishshubham/maintaining-context-in-chatbots-2016b6a5b7c6#.4b10epgv6).

Comment: I'm currently working on a generative chatbot, and it looks like bot-context is more suitable for a retrieval one